# Animating full screen SVG Overlay

Tags: javascript, css, svg

I am trying to use this example found on Tympanus.net to create a cool animated menu:

https://tympanus.net/Development/FullscreenOverlayStyles/index9.html

For the life of me I cannot figure out how to animate the path to open from the top left to the bottom right, I can see the path and path to, but I do not understand the co-ordinates. I have created a codepen to see if I can get it to 
work but I am completely stuck.

```js
/*!
 * classie - class helper functions
 * from bonzo https://github.com/ded/bonzo
 * 
 * classie.has( elem, 'my-class' ) -> true/false
 * classie.add( elem, 'my-new-class' )
 * classie.remove( elem, 'my-unwanted-class' )
 * classie.toggle( elem, 'my-class' )
 */

/*jshint browser: true, strict: true, undef: true */
/*global define: false */

(function(window) {
  'use strict';

  // class helper functions from bonzo https://github.com/ded/bonzo
  function classReg(className) {
    return new RegExp("(^|\\s+)" + className + "(\\s+|$)");
  }

  // classList support for class management
  // altho to be fair, the api sucks because it won't accept multiple classes at once
  var hasClass, addClass, removeClass;

  if ('classList' in document.documentElement) {
    hasClass = function(elem, c) {
      return elem.classList.contains(c);
    };
    addClass = function(elem, c) {
      elem.classList.add(c);
    };
    removeClass = function(elem, c) {
      elem.classList.remove(c);
    };
  } else {
    hasClass = function(elem, c) {
      return classReg(c).test(elem.className);
    };
    addClass = function(elem, c) {
      if (!hasClass(elem, c)) {
        elem.className = elem.className + ' ' + c;
      }
    };
    removeClass = function(elem, c) {
      elem.className = elem.className.replace(classReg(c), ' ');
    };
  }

  function toggleClass(elem, c) {
    var fn = hasClass(elem, c) ? removeClass : addClass;
    fn(elem, c);
  }

  var classie = {
    // full names
    hasClass: hasClass,
    addClass: addClass,
    removeClass: removeClass,
    toggleClass: toggleClass,
    // short names
    has: hasClass,
    add: addClass,
    remove: removeClass,
    toggle: toggleClass
  };

  // transport
  if (typeof define === 'function' && define.amd) {
    // AMD
    define(classie);
  } else {
    // browser global
    window.classie = classie;
  }

})(window);
(function() {
  var triggerBttn = document.getElementById('trigger-overlay'),
    overlay = document.querySelector('div.overlay'),
    closeBttn = overlay.querySelector('button.overlay-close');
  transEndEventNames = {
      'WebkitTransition': 'webkitTransitionEnd',
      'MozTransition': 'transitionend',
      'OTransition': 'oTransitionEnd',
      'msTransition': 'MSTransitionEnd',
      'transition': 'transitionend'
    },
    transEndEventName = transEndEventNames[Modernizr.prefixed('transition')],
    support = {
      transitions: Modernizr.csstransitions
    };
  s = Snap(overlay.querySelector('svg')),
    path = s.select('path'),
    pathConfig = {
      from: path.attr('d'),
      to: overlay.getAttribute('data-path-to')
    };

  function toggleOverlay() {
    if (classie.has(overlay, 'open')) {
      classie.remove(overlay, 'open');
      classie.add(overlay, 'close');

      var onEndTransitionFn = function(ev) {
        classie.remove(overlay, 'close');
      };

      path.animate({
        'path': pathConfig.from
      }, 400, mina.linear, onEndTransitionFn);
    } else if (!classie.has(overlay, 'close')) {
      classie.add(overlay, 'open');
      path.animate({
        'path': pathConfig.to
      }, 400, mina.linear);
    }
  }

  triggerBttn.addEventListener('click', toggleOverlay);
  closeBttn.addEventListener('click', toggleOverlay);
})();
```

```css
.svgcontainer {
  width: 600px;
  height: 300px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border: 1px solid red;
}


/* Overlay style */
.overlay {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: rgba(28, 105, 212, 0.95);
}

/* Overlay closing cross */
.overlay .overlay-close {
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  position: absolute;
  right: 20px;
  top: 20px;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: none;
  font-size: 18px;
  color: white;
  outline: none;
  z-index: 100;
}

/* Menu style */
.overlay nav {
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  height: 60%;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}

.overlay ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
}

.overlay ul li {
  display: block;
  height: 20%;
  height: calc(100% / 5);
  min-height: 54px;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
}

.overlay ul li a {
  font-size: 54px;
  font-weight: 300;
  display: block;
  color: #fff;
  -webkit-transition: color 0.2s;
  transition: color 0.2s;
}

.overlay ul li a:hover,
.overlay ul li a:focus {
  color: #f0f0f0;
}


/* Effects */
.overlay-cornershape {
  background: transparent;
  visibility: hidden;
  -webkit-transition: visibility 0s 0.5s;
  transition: visibility 0s 0.5s;
}

.overlay-cornershape.open {
  visibility: visible;
  -webkit-transition: none;
  transition: none;
}

.overlay-cornershape svg {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.overlay-cornershape .overlay-path {
  fill: rgba(153, 204, 51, 0.9);
  fill: rgba(28, 105, 212, 0.95);
}

.overlay-cornershape nav,
.overlay-cornershape .overlay-close {
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.4s 0.4s;
  transition: opacity 0.4s 0.4s;
}

.overlay-cornershape.open nav,
.overlay-cornershape.open .overlay-close {
  opacity: 1;
  -webkit-transition-delay: 0.4s;
  transition-delay: 0.4s;
}

.overlay-cornershape.close nav,
.overlay-cornershape.close .overlay-close {
  -webkit-transition-delay: 0s;
  transition-delay: 0s;
}

@media screen and (max-height: 30.5em) {
  .overlay nav {
    height: 70%;
    font-size: 34px;
  }
  .overlay ul li {
    min-height: 34px;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/snap.svg/0.5.1/snap.svg-min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/modernizr/2.8.3/modernizr.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <button id="trigger-overlay" type="button">Open Overlay</button>
</div>
<!-- /container -->
<!-- open/close -->
<div class="overlay overlay-cornershape" data-path-to="m 0,0 1439.999975,0 0,805.99999 -1439.999975,0 z">
  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 1440 806" preserveAspectRatio="none">
    <path class="overlay-path" d="m 0,0 1439.999975,0 0,805.99999 0,-805.99999 z" />
  </svg>
  <button type="button" class="overlay-close">Close</button>
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Work</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Clients</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</div>
```

https://codepen.io/jenkinspg/pen/wqGMoV

Please can someone help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You jut have to reverse (horizontally flip) the two path definitions.  What may not be obvious is that they are using a lower-case `m`, so each coordinate pair is relative to the last coordinate pair.

So for example, the start path in the original is:

```
m 0,0 1440,0 0,806 0,-806 z
```

Those points are top-left, top-right, bottom-right, top-right (in that order).  And it animates to:

```
m 0,0 1440,0 0,806 -1440,0 z
```

Or: top-left, top-right, bottom-right, bottom-left.  So in other words, the last point moves from the top right to the bottom left.

To go from top left to bottom right instead, we have to reverse the order of the coordinates in that shape. So from:

```
m 1440,0 -1440,0 0,806 0,-806 z  (TR, TL, BL, TL)
```

to:

```
m 1440,0 -1440,0 0,806 1440,0 z  (TR, TL, BL, BR)
```

```js
/*!
 * classie - class helper functions
 * from bonzo https://github.com/ded/bonzo
 * 
 * classie.has( elem, 'my-class' ) -> true/false
 * classie.add( elem, 'my-new-class' )
 * classie.remove( elem, 'my-unwanted-class' )
 * classie.toggle( elem, 'my-class' )
 */

/*jshint browser: true, strict: true, undef: true */
/*global define: false */

(function(window) {
  'use strict';

  // class helper functions from bonzo https://github.com/ded/bonzo
  function classReg(className) {
    return new RegExp("(^|\\s+)" + className + "(\\s+|$)");
  }

  // classList support for class management
  // altho to be fair, the api sucks because it won't accept multiple classes at once
  var hasClass, addClass, removeClass;

  if ('classList' in document.documentElement) {
    hasClass = function(elem, c) {
      return elem.classList.contains(c);
    };
    addClass = function(elem, c) {
      elem.classList.add(c);
    };
    removeClass = function(elem, c) {
      elem.classList.remove(c);
    };
  } else {
    hasClass = function(elem, c) {
      return classReg(c).test(elem.className);
    };
    addClass = function(elem, c) {
      if (!hasClass(elem, c)) {
        elem.className = elem.className + ' ' + c;
      }
    };
    removeClass = function(elem, c) {
      elem.className = elem.className.replace(classReg(c), ' ');
    };
  }

  function toggleClass(elem, c) {
    var fn = hasClass(elem, c) ? removeClass : addClass;
    fn(elem, c);
  }

  var classie = {
    // full names
    hasClass: hasClass,
    addClass: addClass,
    removeClass: removeClass,
    toggleClass: toggleClass,
    // short names
    has: hasClass,
    add: addClass,
    remove: removeClass,
    toggle: toggleClass
  };

  // transport
  if (typeof define === 'function' && define.amd) {
    // AMD
    define(classie);
  } else {
    // browser global
    window.classie = classie;
  }

})(window);
(function() {
  var triggerBttn = document.getElementById('trigger-overlay'),
    overlay = document.querySelector('div.overlay'),
    closeBttn = overlay.querySelector('button.overlay-close');
  transEndEventNames = {
      'WebkitTransition': 'webkitTransitionEnd',
      'MozTransition': 'transitionend',
      'OTransition': 'oTransitionEnd',
      'msTransition': 'MSTransitionEnd',
      'transition': 'transitionend'
    },
    transEndEventName = transEndEventNames[Modernizr.prefixed('transition')],
    support = {
      transitions: Modernizr.csstransitions
    };
  s = Snap(overlay.querySelector('svg')),
    path = s.select('path'),
    pathConfig = {
      from: path.attr('d'),
      to: overlay.getAttribute('data-path-to')
    };

  function toggleOverlay() {
    if (classie.has(overlay, 'open')) {
      classie.remove(overlay, 'open');
      classie.add(overlay, 'close');

      var onEndTransitionFn = function(ev) {
        classie.remove(overlay, 'close');
      };

      path.animate({
        'path': pathConfig.from
      }, 400, mina.linear, onEndTransitionFn);
    } else if (!classie.has(overlay, 'close')) {
      classie.add(overlay, 'open');
      path.animate({
        'path': pathConfig.to
      }, 400, mina.linear);
    }
  }

  triggerBttn.addEventListener('click', toggleOverlay);
  closeBttn.addEventListener('click', toggleOverlay);
})();
```

```css
.svgcontainer {
  width: 600px;
  height: 300px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border: 1px solid red;
}


/* Overlay style */
.overlay {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: rgba(28, 105, 212, 0.95);
}

/* Overlay closing cross */
.overlay .overlay-close {
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  position: absolute;
  right: 20px;
  top: 20px;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: none;
  font-size: 18px;
  color: white;
  outline: none;
  z-index: 100;
}

/* Menu style */
.overlay nav {
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  height: 60%;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}

.overlay ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
}

.overlay ul li {
  display: block;
  height: 20%;
  height: calc(100% / 5);
  min-height: 54px;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
}

.overlay ul li a {
  font-size: 54px;
  font-weight: 300;
  display: block;
  color: #fff;
  -webkit-transition: color 0.2s;
  transition: color 0.2s;
}

.overlay ul li a:hover,
.overlay ul li a:focus {
  color: #f0f0f0;
}


/* Effects */
.overlay-cornershape {
  background: transparent;
  visibility: hidden;
  -webkit-transition: visibility 0s 0.5s;
  transition: visibility 0s 0.5s;
}

.overlay-cornershape.open {
  visibility: visible;
  -webkit-transition: none;
  transition: none;
}

.overlay-cornershape svg {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.overlay-cornershape .overlay-path {
  fill: rgba(153, 204, 51, 0.9);
  fill: rgba(28, 105, 212, 0.95);
}

.overlay-cornershape nav,
.overlay-cornershape .overlay-close {
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.4s 0.4s;
  transition: opacity 0.4s 0.4s;
}

.overlay-cornershape.open nav,
.overlay-cornershape.open .overlay-close {
  opacity: 1;
  -webkit-transition-delay: 0.4s;
  transition-delay: 0.4s;
}

.overlay-cornershape.close nav,
.overlay-cornershape.close .overlay-close {
  -webkit-transition-delay: 0s;
  transition-delay: 0s;
}

@media screen and (max-height: 30.5em) {
  .overlay nav {
    height: 70%;
    font-size: 34px;
  }
  .overlay ul li {
    min-height: 34px;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/snap.svg/0.5.1/snap.svg-min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/modernizr/2.8.3/modernizr.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <button id="trigger-overlay" type="button">Open Overlay</button>
</div>
<!-- /container -->
<!-- open/close -->
<div class="overlay overlay-cornershape" data-path-to="m 1440,0 -1440,0 0,806 1440,0 z">
  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 1440 806" preserveAspectRatio="none">
    <path class="overlay-path" d="m 1440,0 -1440,0 0,806 0,-806 z" />
  </svg>
  <button type="button" class="overlay-close">Close</button>
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Work</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Clients</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</div>
```

Comment: Wow, thanks Paul, that makes so much sense! Thank you :)